# strange error in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, initialization

hello everyone I have this snippet of the code:

```
    void* Init(int N) {
     Hand * DS = new Hand(N);
    return (void*)DS;
//DS is static defined somewhere...
```

every time when I check in Debugger I receive the same error:

```
mi_cmd_var_create: unable to create variable objec
```

can somebody please explain why?
P.S. I know that this implementation of the function is not good, but it is what I have... Constructor of the Hand works perfectly!

Comment: "Hand *" shouldn't be togheter, like "Hand*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy](http://embdev.net/topic/129677) with the same problem solved it like:

> If you have variables in your watch
>   window that you later eliminate from
>   your code then attempt to debug again
>   this error is generated. The fix is to
>   also delete the variable from the
>   watch list. At least this is how it
>   works in Eclipse Europa.